How do I work around the texture bug in Rayman 2?
I'm running the Ubisoft Connect version of the game on an Intel IRIS XE laptop running Windows 11 (build 26100.2605) with DirectX 12 and most of the time due to compatibility issues textures for particle effects and other smaller in game objects with textures show up as a rectangle that is the size of the texture but sometimes the problem worsens where no trace of the texture is displayed and this is happening in the area of the Sanctuary of Water and Ice where you need to climb over the guardian of water and ice with the purple lums. Since I can't see them, this makes this area extremely hard to play.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
